# Reactjs and this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, fluxible

I m actually trying to develop a simple application using stores and actions and react components using fluxible and I m facing a problem.

In fact, in my component method add(), "this" is undefined...

I dont know what is the problem...

Here's my component:

import React from 'react';

```
class Client extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
    }

    add(e){
      this.context.dispatch('ADD_ITEM', {name:'Marvin'});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Client</h2>
                <p>List of all the clients</p>
                <button onClick={this.add}>Click Me</button>
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }


}

Client.contextTypes = {
    dispatch: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Client;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your button:

```
<button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I think the this is not the good one. I need the one of my class and it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html):

> Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that they don't automatically bind this to the instance. You'll have to explicitly use .bind(this) or arrow functions =>.

So either you bind the function (which I find tedious):

```
<button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
```

Or you can enable and leverage [Babel React ES6+ arrow functions feature](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/#arrow-functions):

```
add = (e) => {
    this.context.dispatch('ADD_ITEM', {name:'Marvin'});
}
```

Comment: After doing it, I have this.context is undefined... :-/

Comment: Well, that depends on something else. Maybe you are missing some function call on the class? https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible#usage